# Does xgoogle still work? If not, what's a good what's a good substitute?

Tags: screen-scraping, xgoogle

I run the following code but it does not work. This is from the readmefile of the xgoogle library.

```
from xgoogle.search import GoogleSearch

gs = GoogleSearch("hi")
gs.results_per_page = 25
results = gs.get_results()

print results
```

This returns an empty list. I've seen some discussion on the interwebs where they say it's not working anymore.

Comment: No this xgoogle no longer working as google wont allow automated search. you can use the custom api of Google for it.